# Accessing address of members of a struct variable using pointer to that structure

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

```
#include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node *next;
    };

    struct node *node1;

    struct node node2;

    node2.data = 200;
    node2.next = NULL;

    cout<<"address of node2: "<<&node2<<endl;

    cout<<"address of node2.data: "<<&node2.data<<endl;

    cout<<"address of node2.next: "<<&node2.next<<endl;

    cout<<"value of node2 data: "<<node2.data<<endl;

    cout<<"value of node2 next is: "<<node2.next<<endl;

    node1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    node1->data = 100;

    node1->next = NULL;

    cout<<"value of node1 data: "<<node1->data<<endl;

    cout<<"value of node1 next: "<<node1->next<<endl;

    cout<<"address of node1 variable is: "<<&node1<<endl;

    cout<<"address of node1 data variable is: "<<&node1->data<<endl;

    cout<<"address of node1 next variable is: "<<&node1->next<<endl;

    cout<<"value stored at node1 variable is: "<<node1<<endl;

    }
```

I wanted to print the address of the members of a struct variable using the pointers to that structure. As it can be seen in my above code example, I have used &node1->next and &node1->data to print the addresses. It seems to be printing the correct addresses because I am able to access the values by dereferencing the address returned by &node1->next and &node1->data. *(&node1->next) and *(&node1->data) returns the values correctly.

But I do not understand how the notations "&node1-> data" and "&node1->next" are returning the address of the members of the struct variable. I accidentally discovered that &node1->data and &node1->next printed the addresses. Whereas with other notations like &node2.data and &node2.next, I was able to logically come up with the notations to print the addresses, but while using pointer to struct to print the address, I accidentally discovered them instead of being able to logically come up with the correct notation.

I want to know whether whatever I have come up with is the correct usage to print the addresses of the member variables and if yes how is it the correct representation ?

Comment: @tobi303 question is how would you print the address of the members of a struct variable using pointer to that struct ? would you use &pointer_var->data_member ? and if yes, how does this actually return data ? it is confusing to visualize this notation in the context of accessing addresses using it

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in C++?

Comment: I think I figured the answer, but I would still like to hear from experienced developers in C/C++. we use notation (*node1).next or node1->next to access(or print) value of next variable in struct. And in order to print the address we would just append the & sign to &(node1->next) or &((*node1).next). The use of brackets makes it more easier to understand.

Comment: @tobi303 thanks a lot ! that is a correct explanation. The mistake I did was I was trying to understand the pointers to struct by comparing it with a normal pointer to an integer variable. If we had a pointer to integer variable, then to print that integer variables address, we would simply print the value in the pointer (cout<<pointer_var;). Pointers to struct work differently. The confusion arises because of the dereferencing operator " * ". Like in example &((*node1).data), we already have a star, so ideally a beginner like me would expect node1.data to return the address. haha

Comment: actually, no it wasnt a good explanation. I will delete the comments and refer you to the answer that was given in the meantime

Comment: @BoundaryImposition sorry sir, malloc worked just fine in my C++ program. But since you have asked that question, I believe there are better alternatives to it. I will look it up and learn what should rightfully used :) I will also check the merits and de-merits of malloc in C++

Comment: @livetolearn: Sure, also sleeping in a cardboard box "works just fine"

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know whether whatever I have come up with is the correct usage to print the addresses of the member variables and if yes how is it the correct representation ?

Yes, it is correct.

The indirection operator or "arrow" `->` returns a reference to a member of the pointed object. So, the argument of the address-of-operator `&` is the member. The adderess-of returns the address of that object i.e. the address of the member. Therefore, logically the correct way to get the address of the member is to first apply arrow operator to get the object, and then the address-of-operator like so:

```
auto* pointer_to_object = get_the_object();
auto* address_of_member = &pointer_to_object->name_of_member;
```

---

> It seems to be printing the correct addresses because I am able to access the values by dereferencing the address returned by `&node1->next` and `&node1->data`. `*(&node1->next)` and `*(&node1->data)` returns the values correctly.

This should be quite obvious. The dereference operation is the inverse of address-of operation, so applying those two in sequence will cancel each other out. `*&node1->data` is equivalent to `node1->data`, which indeed returns you the value of the member.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
1. "arrow" -> returns a reference to a member of the pointed object", so in my example the member would be the "data" variable and object would be "node1" (pointer to structure) ?
2. If arrow returned just reference to the data member, then how are we able to print the value stored in data by using node1->data ? (please bear with me if this is a bad question)

Comment: @livetolearn 1. The object that I talk about would be `*node1` i.e. the object that `node1` points to. 2. Because that's how references work.